# What do the following $\varepsilon$-balls in $S^{1}$ look like? And induced topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, circles, quotient-spaces

Define a metric on $S^{1}:=[0,1)/_{0\sim1}$ by $$d_{1}(x,y)=\min\{|x-y\mod1|,1-|x-y\mod1|\}.$$
Given an $x\in S^{1}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, what does the '$\varepsilon$-ball around $x$' (or interval) in $S^{1}$ look like in this metric?

Also, is $d(x,y):=|x-y|$ a metric on $S^{1}$ and does it induce the same topology as $d_{1}$?

Comment: I'm confused.  For, say, $m=3$, this doesn't seem to be a metric at all because $d_3(\frac 13, \frac 23)=0$ but$ \frac 13 \neq \frac 23$.

Comment: I'm sorry, ignore the $m$. (see edit)

Comment: How can you identity $0$ and $1$ in $[0,1)$?